# What is HStack { } technically?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I’m starting with SwiftUI and very often there is:

```
HStack {
    Button()
    Text()
    …

}
```

I think `HStack` etc. is a struct, but what pattern are these curly brackets defining in Swift?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/6/5/trailing-closure-syntax, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder, https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md

Comment: This is a call to the `HStack` initializer [init(alignment:spacing:content:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/hstack/init(alignment:spacing:content:)) with a `@ViewBuilder`[Trailing closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/closures/#Trailing-Closures).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layout